# Swift Inheritance with custom array

Tags: ios, swift

```
class RecipeBrain: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var pictureUrl: String
    var likes = 0
    var ingredients: [Ingredient]
    var method: [String]

    init(name: String, pictureUrl: String, ingredients: [Ingredient], method: [String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.pictureUrl = pictureUrl
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.method = method
    }
}

class Ingredient{
    var name: String
    var quantity: Double
    var unit: String

    init(name: String, quantity: Double, unit: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.unit = unit
    }
}

class AddRecipe {
    var recipeBrain = [RecipeBrain]()
    var ingredients = [Ingredient]()
    var ingredient = Ingredient(name: "apple", quantity: 1.0, unit: "Kg")
    ingredients.append(ingredient)
    var recipe1 = RecipeBrain(name: "Recipe1", pictureUrl: "nil", ingrexdients: ingredients, method: ["Method"])
    recipeBrain.append(recipe1)
}
```

I am trying to build a recipe app in Swift. Problem is creating the ingredients for it where I require a string,double,string.

How I imagined : an ingredient is an array of Ingredients. and to create a new recipe I just .append it to the recipeBrain

Main problem : when I try to append a new recipe to the recipeBrain array It says that the recipe1 is not declared.

( The AddRecipe class purpose is only testing with static data )

I changed it to  recipeBrain.append(recipe1) But I still get the error : expected declaration , same with ingredients when I try to append

Comment: Did you mean `recipeBrain.append(recipe1)` on the last line?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append recipe and ingredient objects into their arrays in body of AddRecipe class, but you can't.

if you do this in body of a method everything will be ok, for example in init() method:

```
class AddRecipe {
var recipeBrain = [RecipeBrain]()
var ingredients = [Ingredient]()

init()
{
    var ingredient = Ingredient(name: "apple", quantity: 1.0, unit: "Kg")
    ingredients.append(ingredient)
    var recipe1 = RecipeBrain(name: "Recipe1", pictureUrl: "nil", ingredients: ingredients, method: ["Method"])
    recipeBrain.append(recipe1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error message because you have tried to write code in a class declaration.  You can only declare items such as properties, functions, enumerations and other classes directly inside a class declaration.  Code, such as `ingredients.append(ingredient)` needs to go inside a function.

I would suggest that you move this code into a class function of your `RecipeBrain` class (or indeed put it somewhere else entirely, such as a view controller, but you haven't shown how your app is structured):

```
class RecipeBrain: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var pictureUrl: String
    var likes = 0
    var ingredients: [Ingredient]
    var method: [String]

    init(name: String, pictureUrl: String, ingredients: [Ingredient], method: [String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.pictureUrl = pictureUrl
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.method = method
    }

    class func addRecipe() -> [RecipeBrain] {
        var recipeBrain = [RecipeBrain]()
        var ingredients = [Ingredient]()
        let ingredient = Ingredient(name: "apple", quantity: 1.0, unit: "Kg")
        ingredients.append(ingredient)
        let recipe1 = RecipeBrain(name: "Recipe1", pictureUrl: "nil", ingredients: ingredients, method: ["Method"])
        recipeBrain.append(recipe1)
        return recipeBrain
    }
}
```

Now you can say `let recipeBrain = RecipeBrain.addRecipe()` and `recipeBrain` will be an array of `RecipeBrain` containing a single `RecipeBrain`